# Smooth cubic curve is union of line and conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Why is it necessarily true that given a smooth cubic curve $S_{3} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{3}_{\mathbb{C}}$, containing a line $L$, ($L \subset S_{3}$) that: 
$$ S_{3} \cap \Pi = L \cup C$$ 
For a conic $C$ and plane $\Pi$ where $L \subset \Pi$?

This is stated in my lecture notes without any proof. As I understand it the following is true:

1.The statement implies that the intersection of a plane and a cubic must itself define a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d \le 3$.

2.Bezout's theorem should imply $C_{1} \cap C_{2} \le d_{1}d_{2}$. $(d_{1} = \text{degree} \; S_{3}  ,d_{2}=\text{degree} = \; \Pi $)

3.Any line $L$ will have an uncountable number of points, and the union will not remove any of these.

How do we reconcile (2) and (3) - or, better, how can I actually prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean that $S_3$ is a smooth cubic *surface*?

Comment: Note that Bezout's theorem describes how *generic* things intersect. For example, if you take two copies of the same line $L,$ clearly $L \cap L$ is again $L,$ not a single point.

Comment: Yes I was goinig to ask the same, otherwise this doesn't make much sense right?

Answer (score 1):

Both notation and the situation you are describing suggest that $S_3$ must be a surface. In that case everything you said makes perfect sense and the cubic curve (union of line and conic) would be intersection of the surface and the plane.

Otherwise, if you pick a plane containing the line (this is not a general plane!) then the intersection with the "remaining" degree 2 part or your curve wouldn't be a conic, but just two points (for a general plane). So the point of this paragraph is that it shouldn't be difficult to come up with a counterexample to your claim, and that actually most of the examples you would try to write down would fail.